# Resizing buttons when the background resizes in android

Tags: android

I was working with my thesis and it was an android game Spot the difference. so I have many buttons everywhere in my layout. in my graphical layout i use 4.7in WXGA because it was the compatible device config with my phone i was trying to use. but when i installed it in another phone which has a different size the buttons moved and it don't resize as the background resizes. Please help me on how to make the button don't change its position in different size of phones.

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgethnic">

<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="625dp"
android:layout_height="303dp"
android:background="@drawable/gameilocosnorte"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginLeft="530dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn01"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="442dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox" android:layout_marginTop="85dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn02"
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox" android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"/>


<Button
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/btn03"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginLeft="430dp" android:layout_marginTop="220dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Small Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn4"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginLeft="340dp" android:layout_marginTop="45dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn04"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn5"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginTop="140dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn05"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
android:background="@drawable/iconbox"
android:layout_marginTop="140dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="0"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/iconstarthree"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="0 of 1"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnhow"
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:background="@drawable/btnqmark"
android:layout_marginLeft="590dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should use wrap_content in 2nd relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `android:layout_above`, `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_toRightOf` rather than placing everything with margins.

This would make your layout far easier to maintain, because it allows you to move a button so that other related buttons are moved along automatically.

You should also use styles defined in `styles.xml` for all buttons with similar properties, in order to avoid unnecessary code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="625dp"
android:layout_height="303dp"
android:background="@drawable/gameilocosnorte"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">
```

To

```
<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gameilocosnorte"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">
```